# How to generate a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, build.gradle, docker-image, docker-build

I try to create a docker image based on my java gradle web application. 
I add plugin and build in my `build.gradle` as shown below.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'docker'

buildscript {
  repositories { mavenCentral() }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.1'
  }
}
```

I didn't specify the java version as in gradle's default `sourceCompatibility` is 1.7

After execute `./gradlew distDocker`
`build` folder is generated

```
docker/application-b35a946bf5b.tgz
docker/Dockerfile
classes/
distributions/
libs/
resources/
scripts/
tmp/
```

Can i create docker images based on `docker/application-b35a946bf5b.tgz` and `docker/Dockerfile`

I am new to docker.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: I am new to gradle. 

That being said, you can create a docker image by "docker build"-ing from Dockerfile (default is you need to be in the same directory as "Dockerfile") or by "docker commit"-ing your running container. 

From you question, you have a java application that you want to build a docker image. Just "FROM java8" and COPY your dist. Then, run docker build manually. 

When you are familiar with docker, you can include that step in gradle.

Comment: Command `docker help build` as well as the [starter docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) should be a good start point... which will probably lead you to try something like `cd docker && docker build . -t my_app_service:my_tag`